# Given , $X$ is a standard normal R.V , I know $E[X|X>c]$ = $\frac{\phi(c)}{1 - \Phi(c)}$ , how do i derive a similar formula for $var[X|X>c]$

Tags: probability, variance, conditional-probability, random-variable, conditional-expectation

I can derive $E[X|X>c]$ = $\frac{\phi(c)}{1 - \Phi(c)}$ , using the trick $- \int \frac{d \phi(x)}{dx} = \int x \phi(x) dx$. How do I do a similar thing to derive $var[X|X>c]$.

Comment: Integrate by parts.

Comment: Can you please explain the trick you stated... Then it can be extended...

Comment: @SandipanKarmakar - it's not a trick, really.  Just take the derivative of $\phi(x)$ and you'll see where the equality comes from.

Answer (score 1):

I think I figured it out , 
$ var[X|X>c] = E[X^2|X>c] - (E[X|X>c])^2$
$$
E[X^2|X>c] = \frac{\int_{x=c}^{x=\inf}x^2 \phi(x)dx}{1 - \Phi(c)}
$$
Integrating by parts , let $ u = x$ and $ v = x\phi(x)$
$$
= x\int x\phi(x)dx - \int \int x \phi(x)dx
$$
Using the fact that $ \int x\phi(x) dx = -\phi(x)$
$$
E[X^2|X>c] = [x\phi(x)]_{c}^{\inf} + \int_{c}^{\inf} \phi(x) dx
= [-x\phi(x)]_{c}^{\inf} +[\Phi(x)]_{c}^{\inf}
$$
$$
E[X^2|X>c] =\frac{ c \phi(c) + [1 - \Phi(c)]}{1 - \Phi(c)}
$$
Therefore , $$
var[X|X>c] = \frac{ c \phi(c) + [1 - \Phi(c)]}{1 - \Phi(c)} - [\frac{\phi(c)}{1-\Phi(c)}]^2
$$